# New Customizer Menu (WP 4.3) - how is called?

Tags: theme-customizer, api

The new "Menu" in Customizer got released in 4.3. I need to know how to "get" to it.

```
<?php $wp_customizer->get_panel(' ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ');?>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all registered panels with `$wp_customizer->panels()`

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/panels/